# How to replace URL.createObjectURL() for blob cases

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have the function below and using the deprecated URL.createObjectURL() method:

```
const downloadExceptionFile = async () => {
    const resp = await getExceptionFile();

    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('download', 'excecoes.xlsx');
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([resp.data]));
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    link.remove();
  };
```

I`m using react, i try use `this.srcObject` and  `this.src` as recomended in `HTMLMediaElement.srcObject` documentation, but, i just got an undefined error in my face.

How can i replace `URL.createObjectURL()` since this method its deprecated?

Comment: "Just got an undefined error in my face" doesn't really help us help you.

Comment: Either way, where did you get the information that `createObjectURL` would be deprecated? [MDN doesn't seem to indicate that.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)

Comment: @AKX at the same link that you sended, there is a warning in yellow about to replace this method, and at the end of page there is a sign that its a deprecated method.

Comment: Yes, that yellow box says "to attach streams to media elements" – but that's not what you're doing, you're doing a download link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short:

You don't need to change that code since [`URL.createObjectURL()` is not deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL).

The specific use case of creating an object URL to attach to a media element (e.g. `<video>`) is, and for that you should use [`.srcObject`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject)  instead.